# issues replacing link values on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, internationalization

I have a little issue with the replacement of the `<a>` values, I have this code:

```
$('a').each(function() { 
    var $this = $(this),
    aHref = $this.attr('href');  //get the value of an attribute 'href'
    $this.attr('href', aHref.replace(location.host,''+location.host+'/'+plang+''));
});
```

**What am I try to do?**

I am tring to replace all the links like this: `http://example.com/?p=1` to `http://example.com/es/?p=1` the code works fine for all the static links, like the menu, the logo link, the footer links and the pagination, but don't work for the post or pages links, is any other way for make that change?

The Website use the google translate jQuery script, and that is why I need change the language using: /en/?p=1 or /fr/?p=1, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you adjust it in `wp-config.php`? And yes, you can also do this dynamically (despite the values being constant from the point on where you define them):

```
define('WP_SITEURL', ...);
define('WP_HOME',    ...);
```

Comment: awesome thanks, but i can make it like a plugin without make it from the wp-config.php? because the site change the /en/... /es/... part depending the language of the user, and i want make it like a plugin.